# Replacing Multiple XML Node values in TextPad

Tags: textpad

I have a file with "XMLNodeName "value" CloseXMLNodeName" The "value" changes for each entry of NodeName -

I need to replace all the 'value'  with blank. How do I do this in Textpad?

Comment: Is this XML, or does your example accurately reflect what you are attempting to do?

Answer (score 0):

textpad?  I'm not familiar with that, do you have to do it with that tool?  Most editors will have a find/replace function and allow you to use regular expressions.  You could simply match on all attributes and replace the value with nothing.  Is the attribute the same for each tag?

This might be easier if you had a sample of the file you were trying to modify

EDIT - "unknown (Google)" - I am not quite sure someone can help you with a regular expression without an example of the text you are trying to match.  Can you edit your post and show us an example please?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I need the regex in textpad - I am thinking Nodename.* would work ?

Comment: TextPad supports regex Replace.  On the version that I run (4.6) there's a 'Regular expression' option available on the Replace dialog.

Comment: Thanks Jay, what regex do I use (what goes in the find box and the replace box? I need to replace all nodes with value blank, the node names are the same)